# django-registration: Chinese user cannot register due to invalid characters in password

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-registration

Somebody from Singapore reported that he cannot sign up to my website. The website is a Django project and we use django-registration module. The error message says about password field that:

```
this value may contain only letters, numbers and etc
```

The user says he is using only latin alphabet in his password, but he has a Chinese keyboard and his system (Windows) is configured for Chinese characters input. I don't know how to reproduce the problem in my development environment.

Does anyone know what could cause this problem? Is django-registration meant to work with non-ASCII characters? The user says he was using only latin characters, so perhaps the problem is that his password was encoded as Unicode, but I'm not really sure about it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is not with the password, but it is with the user name. See the function `UserCreationForm` and `UserChangeForm` [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py)

```
username = forms.RegexField(
        label=_("Username"), max_length=30, regex=r"^[\w.@+-]+$",
        help_text = _("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and "
                      "@/./+/-/_ only."),
        error_messages = {
            'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and "
                         "@/./+/-/_ characters.")})
```

May be he is using some latin character which is not satisfying this regex.

You may get this error while not matching this regex.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let me verify your finding with the user before I accept you answer - I just sent an email to him asking to try to sign up again making sure user name does not have Chinese characters.

Comment: The user says he's trying to enter a name consisting of latin characters only... I'm suspecting it's passed to the server encoded as unicode, but I really have no clue how to test it / reproduce it on my dev box.

Comment: How can I change / overwrite `UserChangeForm` with my own code? `UserChangeForm` is apparently used by `django-registration`. I've seen some suggestions that by inheriting from `UserChangeForm` I can overwrite some of its behaviour with my desired one (in this case: accepting Unicode), but how can I make `django-registration` to know that the new class I derived from `UserChangeForm` is the one it should use?

Comment: thanks for this, I'm closing the question. I've just posted a followup question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357168/how-to-make-django-registration-use-my-customized-usercreationform-and-userchang