# How to make django-registration use my customized UserCreationForm and UserChangeForm?

Tags: python, django, registration, django-registration

I am developing a website using Django 1.4 and `django-registration`

I would like to allow users to create their user names using arbitrary Unicode characters. Currently, if someone tries to register using non-latin characters, he will see an error message. The code responsible for rejecting this kind of non-ASCII usernames is in `UserCreationForm` and `UserChangeForm`, see [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py):

```
username = forms.RegexField(
        label=_("Username"), max_length=30, regex=r"^[\w.@+-]+$",
        help_text = _("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and "
                      "@/./+/-/_ only."),
        error_messages = {
            'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and "
                         "@/./+/-/_ characters.")})
```

Now, I would like to change it. I've seen some suggestions that I should create my own `UserCreationForm`, and creating a derived class with some changed behaviour seems easy enough.

The bit I don't understand is: how to make `django-registration` use my customized `UserCreationForm` and `UserChangeForm`? Obviously, I would like to avoid modifying the source of `django-registration`, if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/views.html

After creating your own registration form you can pass this form to the register view of django-registration. Look for the `registration.backends.default.urls` module

```
url(r'^register/$', register,
     {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend', 
     'form_class': MyRegistrationForm},
```